# Difficulty writing PEG recursive expression grammar with Arpeggio

Tags: grammar, peg, arpeggio, packrat-parsing

My input text might have a simple statement like this:

```
aircraft
```

In my language I call this a *name* which represents a set of instances with various properties.
It yields an *instance_set* of all aircraft instances in this example.

I can apply a *filter* in parenthesis to any instance_set:

```
aircraft(Altitude < ceiling)
```

It yields another, possibly reduced instance_set.
And since it is an instance set, I can filter it yet again:

```
aircraft(Altitude < ceiling)(Speed > min_speed)
```

I foolishly thought I could do something like this in my grammar:

```
instance_set = expr
expr = source / instance_set
source = name filter?
```

It parses my first two cases correctly, but chokes on the last one:

```
 aircraft(Altitude < ceiling)(Speed > min_speed)
```

The error reported being just before the second open paren.

Why doesn't Arpeggio see that there is just a filtered instance_set which is itself a filtered instance set?

I humbly submit my appeal to the peg parsing gods and await insight...

Answer (score 2):

Your first two cases both match `source`. Once `source` is matched, it's matched; that's the PEG contract. So the parser isn't going to explore the alternative.

But suppose it did. How could that help? The rule says that if an `expr` is not a `source`, then it's an `instance_set`. But an `instance_set` is just an `expr`. In other words, an `expr` is either a `source` or it's an `expr`. Clearly the alternative doesn't get us anywhere.

I'm pretty sure Arpeggio has repetitions, which is what you really want here:

```
source = name filter*
```

Comment: Yes, thanks! It did occur to me that I was overthinking the problem and repetitions will solve it for me.